# Question about finetuning model to increase number of classes w/additional data using Tensor Flow Custom Object Detection

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, object, detection

Using Tensorflow's Custom Object Classification API w/ SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320 as the base, I was able to train my model to succesfully detect classes A and B using *Training Data 1* (about 200 images). This performed well on Test Set 1, which only has images of class A and B.

I wanted to add several classes to the model, so I constructed a separate dataset, *Training Data 2* (about 300 images). This dataset contains labeled data for class B, and new classes C, D and E. However it does NOT include data for class A. Upon training the model on this data, it performed well on Test Set 2 which contained only images of B, C, D and E (however the accuracy on B did not go up despite extra data)

Concerned, I checked the accuracy of the model on Test Set 1 again, and as I had assumed, the model didn't recognize class A at all. In this case I'm assuming I didn't actually refine the model but instead retrained the model completely.

**My Question:** Am I correct in assuming I cannot refine the model on a completely separate set of data, and instead if I want to add more classes to my trained model that I must combine *Training Set 1* and *Training Set 2* and train on the entirety of the data?

Thank you!

Comment: This question may be better suited in another forum, seems like a machine learning rather than a programing question

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on your hyperparameters, namely, your learning rate and the number of epochs trained. Higher learning rates will make the model forget the old data faster. Also, be sure not to be overfitting your data, have a validation set as well. Models that have overfit the training data tend to be very sensitive to weight (and data) perturbations.

TLDR. If not trained on all data, ML models tend to forget old data in favor of new data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will keep that in mind.

I should have specified, but my data set is in fact split into Training/Validation sets. 

My apologies, just to clarify one last thing: I currently have data for 5 classes, but my end goal is ~25 classes. Would I be better off setting the number of classes to 25 in the pipeline.config from the beginning and adding data for those classes to my dataset as I get it, or to augment the number of classes as I add the respective data?

Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest to augment the number of classes as you get more classes, because when you get more data you should retrain from scratch using your whole dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! It seems I had quite a misunderstanding of how to finetune a model. When adding new data then, there is no way to avoid training the model from scratch?

Comment: From scratch I mean using the same procedure you employed to train your first model (using MobileNet as a base). As you dataset is small (<1000 images) and should fit in memory I would not bother to recycle the weights. Nevertheless, you can change the output layer, increasing the number of classes, and copy the weights from the old layer to the new layer for the classes that exists on both. Beware of the order (the location of the weights). And then train with your whole data (you may undersample the old data in favor of the new).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of "moving parts". I propose the followings:

1. Take the "SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320" as a basemodel without its last classification layer (argument include_top=False when loading the model), and freeze its parameters using command basemodel.trainable=False
2. Add new prediction layer with command prediction_layer=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) and make other required things (details step by step in page https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning)

After the procedure above verify that you have understanding which parameters of the new network (including "old" convolutional part and your own new prediction layer) are trainable and which are not. Change the hyperparameters if needed.

Next train the network using a standard procedures.

Use directly final number of classes according to your idea (25). If you have no data yet for all classes, do not worry, generate some random images for the purpose, and of course take into account that the results are not valid for the classes with no appropriate data.

For simplicity divide the data - principally independently from the number of classes - to training and test data and nothing more complicated in first hand. When amount of data increases the statistics will diminish problems with sampling. And when training, monitor how the amount of data increase the performance of the classification.

So - in a nutshell - 1) make the network - 2) select which parameters to train - 3) train with one dataset and 4) test with another.

And finally direct answer for the question in title and in the end of the question:

-According to experience first utilize out all performance of the basemodel by training only the last layers of the network. After you are sure no more performance can be found this way, begin to finetune the convolutional layers tuning carefully hyperparameters.

-You can refine the model totally only by using your own new data; this is special benefit and art of transfer learning